# Tablesorter jQuery plugin width of column

Tags: jquery, css

I use the jQuery plugin tablesorter. All the `columns` have the same width.
I change the width of the first column via CSS, but there is no change.

I tried to add `widthFixed: false`:

```
$("#ActivitiesTable").tablesorter(
        { widthFixed: false }
        );
```

Still there is no change in the `column's` width.

How can I change the column's width in a table, when using tablesorter?

Thanks